# What is the best way to preserve Account Team Members on Bulk Owner Changes on Account?

Tags: apex, data-loader, account, account-teams, record-owner

Users can preserve Account Team Members while changing records from the UI. However, during mass owner change via Dataloader on the Account Object, there is no option to keep the Account Team Members.

This official data-loader instruction doesn't work either: [Data Loader Keep Account Team](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.dataLoader.meta/dataLoader/loader_keep_account_teams_config.htm?_ga=2.53598639.683534164.1690170732-398713269.1688636391)

Officially suggested workarounds: [Retaining Account Team](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000390190&type=1)

So, my initial thought is that we can **implement Trigger**, which will hold all the Account Team Members before changing the Account Ownership and, later on, inserting them. Not sure if it would be a good idea to do the same using the **Flow Builder**.

I would like to know if anyone has already implemented it or what kind of implementation would be best for the bulk Account Owner Change.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have the same requirement and tried the trigger approach, but I'm not getting the desired results. For some reason I am able to recreate the ATM records on the "after update" context, but querying the table on the unit test shows that just one ATM record is created. It is weird... We need a DMLOption for this.

Comment: There's an idea for this, by the way: https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000H5Rb3UAF

Answer (score 0):

[XL-Connector](https://www.xappex.com/knowledge-base/installing-enabler/), [XL-Connector 365](https://www.xappex.com/knowledge-base/installing-enabler4excel-365/), and [G-Connector](https://www.xappex.com/knowledge-base/installing-g-connector/) all have this option supported. You can use any one of them depending on whether you want to mass-update from Excel or Google Sheets.
[image]